# THREE.js intersects[0].object.position always returns (0,0,0)

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am displaying some objects on my page using THREE.js. I am able to click objects but I noticed that no matter which object I click, the `intersects[0].object.position` always returns `x=0, y=0, z=0`, while the actual positions of the objects are no doubt different.

Can you review the following code and comment what am I doing wrong?

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2-1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight)*2+1, 0.5);
  projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
  var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, vector.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
  var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(teeth, true);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    //not working
    camera.position.x=intersects[0].object.position.x;
    //not working
    camera.position.y=intersects[0].object.postion.y;
    //working
    intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random()*0xffffff);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the objects position: intersects[0].object.position

the intersect position: intersects[0].position

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2-1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight)*2+1, 0.5);
  projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
  var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, vector.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
  var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(teeth, true);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    //not working
    camera.position.x=intersects[0].point.x;
    //not working
    camera.position.y=intersects[0].point.y;
    //working
    intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random()*0xffffff);
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't find intersects[0].position.x as a valid property. Although there is intersects[0].point.x

Comment: @Gero3.. what I am doing in if(intersects.length > 0) is to change the intersected object position as well. intersects[0].object.position.z=50; Now I don't know how to keep track of the object original position when it was not click, so that I can move other clicked object to their same old position if another object is clicked. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Everything was resolved as soon as I began to pass a reference not to the object with which the intersection occurred, but to its parent: intersects[0].object.parent

```js
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2-1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight)*2+1, 0.5);
  projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
  var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, vector.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
  var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(teeth, true);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {

    camera.position.x=intersects[0].object.parent.position.x;

    camera.position.y=intersects[0].object.parent.postion.y;

    intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random()*0xffffff);
  }
}
```